# Grid coords not updating C#/Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

i have a quick question. I use xamarin and C# to move some grids around the screen, but when ever i use the TranslateTo method, the coords of the grids do not update. The grids move on the screen but they assume their original coords as their current ones. Am i missing an update function or sth? Thanks!

Here is the code i am using for the movement:

```
 public async void changepos(Grid grid)
        {
            double posAX = startergrid.X;
            double posAY = startergrid.Y;
            double posBX = grid.X;
            double posBY = grid.Y;

            await grid.ScaleTo(1.2, 75, Easing.Linear);
            await grid.TranslateTo(posAX - posBX, posAY - posBY, 100, Easing.Linear);
            await startergrid.TranslateTo(posBX - posAX, posBY - posAY, 100, Easing.Linear);

            await grid.ScaleTo(1, 75);
            await startergrid.ScaleTo(1, 75);

        }
```

So i move the grid where the startergrid is and the startergrid where the grid is.

Well nothing so far, i dont know where to start

Comment: You mean value of TranslationX is still 0?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this Xamarin.Forms or what kind of Grid are you working with?

Comment: The method `TranslateTo()` is just a animation, the actual position of grid has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as answer:

The method `TranslateTo()` is just a animation, the actual position of grid has not changed.

For info you can see the doc: [Simple Animations in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple).

Comment: Ok so i just assume i have to create an array of all the X,Y and update them when i use the TranslateTo() method manualy... pff thanks!

Comment: Sure, you can try to do like that!